# Insert a value of 0 into identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert a value of 0 into a column of a table which has existing data. 
The identity column is (1,1). Do I need to delete the existing data in order to insert a value of 0?

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON
INSERT INTO table (id,...) Values(0,.....)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table OFF
```

I tried to run this but the script just hangs.

Comment: The script **hangs**? As in, it runs "forever" without returning a response? If so, interesting. If not, if it instead returns an *error message*, you should describe that error message (including all text)

Comment: Oh goody. Edits that make it clear that *the code in the question* has never been run. Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: You want to insert 0 into an identity column? Why?

Answer (score 2):

```
create table #test (id int identity(0,1), val int)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #test ON
INSERT INTO #test (id,val) Values(0,100)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #test OFF
SELECT * FROM #test
```

```
id          val
----------- -----------
0           100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using set identity_insert table on

```
create table #test (id int identity(1,1), val int)

insert into #test (val) values (10),(11)

set identity_insert #test on

insert into #test (id, val) values (0,12)

set identity_insert #test off
```

But if you have PK or Unique index on id then you will get constraint error

Comment: The code in the question does turn identity_insert on. What, *specifically*, is this answer meant to demonstrate that differentiates it from the code in the question?

Comment: Good point... If it hangs need to understand the actual error why it is getting error...

Comment: I used this on my table that had PK on ID and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the column names for the insert when using `identity_insert`.

```
create table t (id int not null identity(1,1), col varchar(32));
set identity_insert dbo.t on;
insert into dbo.t (id,col) values(0,'test');
set identity_insert dbo.t off;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/VMT42836

returns

```
+----+------+
| id | col  |
+----+------+
|  0 | test |
+----+------+
```

Comment: sorry, I do specify the column names as well